# How to rename columns with the same name so that they're different?

Tags: r

I was combining columns from data tables using `cbind()` and some of these columns happened to have the same name but different data, which R usually catches and changes them by adding a ..1 after the initial column name, but I guess using `cbind()` prevented R from catching it? I want to rename the columns which I would usually do by using `colnames(data)[colnames(data)=="column"] <- column..1` but because these 2 columns have the same name, I can't change one without also changing the other. How do I get around this?

Comment: Just adding multiple arguments at RHS will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename all column with :

```
colnames(data)<-c("col1","col2","col3", etc)
```

or if you know that you have exactly only two columns with the same names, you can do something like:

```
colnames(data)[colnames(data)=="column"] <- c("col1","col2")
```

Another solution is to rename the columns before applying cbind()

Answer (score 2):

One easy way of doing this is to use the `janitor` package.

```
df <- cbind(data.frame(col1 = c(1,2)), data.frame(col1 = c(2,3))) 
df
#>   col1 col1
#> 1    1    2
#> 2    2    3
```

and then we use the `clean_names` function to tidy

```
janitor::clean_names(df)
#>   col1 col1_2
#> 1    1      2
#> 2    2      3
```